# How to check if more than two coordinates are adjacent

Tags: coordinates, solidity

I’m developing some code in solidity, I need to write a function to check whether more than two points are adjacent, given an array with the xs and another array with the ys.
I’m currently blocked because I don’t know how to make it.

This is my pseudocode:

```
    function isCoordsAdjacent(
        uint256 x1,
        uint256 y1,
        uint256 x2,
        uint256 y2
    ) public pure returns (bool) {
        unchecked {
            if (1 == ((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
function testCoords(uint256[] calldata x, uint256[] calldata y) public view returns (bool) {

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {

            if (
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, x, y - 1)
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, (x - 1), y) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, (x - 1), (y + 1)) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, x, (y - 1)) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, x, y) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, x, y + 1) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, (x + 1), (y - 1)) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, (x + 1), y) ||
                isCoordsAdjacent(x, y, (x + 1), (y + 1))
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope you can help me get to the right solution.
Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I fixed the code in this way, but still it doesn't work:

```
    function testCoords(uint256[] calldata x, uint256[] calldata y)
        public
        pure
        returns (bool result)
    {
        unchecked {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                for (uint256 j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
                    if (i == j) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (isCoordsAdjacent(x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j])) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. From what I understand you want to check each point against each other (hence 2 loops).

1. Do not check if a point if adjacent to itself. You should add `if {i==j} continue;` to your code in the inner loop.
2. You need to check i-th element of x and y arrays not x or y itself. You should do `isCoordsAdjacent(x[i], y[i], x[j], y[j])`
3. `isCoordsAdjacent` is already checking adjacency no need for the chain of `||`

Comment: I posted an update, what do I keep getting wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code not working? If it errors the the error else the expected behaviour vs actual

Comment: Sure, this is the [remix link](https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js).
If I give the input [1,2,5], [1,1,1], the testCoords gives me true even if the three coords are not adjacent, just because the first two are. It should give me false instead.

Comment: So you want `true` only if all are adjacent?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that my loop stops after the first iteration, so it shows true even if the last one isn't adjacent